# How to use cakephp export txt file

Tags: cakephp

I'm using cakephp framework.I want to export a database table of a client download in two formats.One is '.csv', the other is a '.txt'.CSV which I have passed 'csvHelper' resolved.Now I want to know how to export '.txt'.Sorry for my poor English, but I think you'll see what I mean, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you set the header for the filename, like this:

```
        $this->response->type('Content-Type: text/csv');
    $this->response->download('myfilename.txt');
```

Here are some functions I put in my appController, so that any controller can output a CSV file if required:

```
    /**
 * Flattens the data that is returned from a find() operation, and puts it into CSV format
 * @param $data
 * @return string
 */
public function _arrayToCsvFile($data){
    $flattenedData = array();
    $exportKeyPair = array();
    foreach($data as $datumKey => $datumDetails){
        $flattenedDatum = Hash::flatten($datumDetails, '.');
        $flattenedData[] = $flattenedDatum;

        // Find all keys
        if($datumKey == 0){
            $exportKeys = array_keys($flattenedDatum);
            $exportKeyPair = array_combine($exportKeys, $exportKeys);
        }
        else {
            $datumKeys = array_keys($flattenedDatum);

            $datumKeyPair = array_combine($datumKeys, $datumKeys);

            // Add the datum keys to the exportKeyPair if it's not already there
            $exportKeyPair = array_merge($exportKeyPair, $datumKeyPair);
        }
    }

    $exportKeyMap = array();
    foreach($exportKeyPair as $exportKey => $exportValue){
        $exportKeyMap[$exportKey] = "";
    }


    $outputCSV = '';

    $outputCSV .= $this->_arrayToCsvLine($exportKeyPair);

    foreach($flattenedData as $flattenedDatumKey => $flattenedDatumDetails){

        // Add any extra keys
        $normalisedDatumDetails = array_merge($exportKeyMap, $flattenedDatumDetails);

        $outputCSV .= $this->_arrayToCsvLine($normalisedDatumDetails);
    }

    return $outputCSV;
}

    /**
 * arrayToCsvLine function - turns an array into a line of CSV data.
 *
 * @access public
 * @param mixed $inputLineArray the input array
 * @param string $separator (default: ")
 * @param string $quote (default: '"')
 * @return string
 */
function _arrayToCsvLine($inputLineArray, $separator = ",", $quote = '"') {
    $outputLine = "";

    $numOutput = 0;

    foreach($inputLineArray as $inputLineKey => $inputLineValue) {
        if($numOutput > 0) {
            $outputLine .= $separator;
        }

        $outputLine .= $quote . str_replace(array('"', "\n", "\r"),array('""', "", ""), $inputLineValue) . $quote;
        $numOutput++;
    }

    $outputLine .=  "\n";

    return $outputLine;

}

/**
 * Serves some CSV contents out to the client
 * @param $csvContents
 * @param array $options
 */
public function _serveCsv($csvContents, $options = array()){

    $defaults = array(
        'modelClass' => $this->modelClass,
        'fileName' => null
    );

    $settings = array_merge($defaults, $options);

    if(empty($settings['fileName'])){
        $settings['fileName'] = strtolower( Inflector::pluralize( $settings['modelClass'] ) ) . '_' . date('Y-m-d_H-i') . '.csv';
    }

    $this->autoRender = false;

    $this->response->type('Content-Type: text/csv');
    $this->response->download($settings['fileName']);
    $this->response->body($csvContents);
}
```

Now in any controller you can do this (note that you can pass the filename to _serveCsv if required):

```
/**
 * admin_export_csv method
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function admin_export_csv() {
    $this->Order->recursive = 0;

    $conditions = array();

    $orders = $this->Order->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));


    $csvContents = $this->_arrayToCsvFile($orders); // Function in AppController

    $this->_serveCsv($csvContents, array('filename' => 'export.txt')); // Function in AppController
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use 
**$this->RequestHandler->respondAs('txt');** to output the correct header.

Please not the header is not set when DEBUG is greater than 2.
And you will still have to build the controller action and set view as ususal.