# Cakephp: Download a string variable as file

Tags: php, cakephp, download, cakephp-2.0

Is it possible to do download a string variable in my code as a file with cakephp ?

For example:

`$myString = "value1;value2;value3\n1;2;3";`

I want to download the string $myString as a csv file without saving it on my server. I just want the user to be able to download the string as a file.

If you have regular php solutions, It can do the job but I prefer to use CakePHP.

Thanks for your help,

Antoine

Comment: No idea about cakePHP but this is [trivial in standard PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249432/export-to-csv-via-php)

Comment: I don't know cake, but Google on "force download php" and you'll get the gist. It's basically just setting some headers and echoing your variable. There isn't really much magic too it.

Comment: Please try to search and read the documentation... https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html & https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-a-string-as-file There is a section about what you want including examples.

Comment: probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391257/how-to-use-cakephp-export-txt-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged this question with cakephp 2.0

As *burzum* points out they have an example exactly for this use case of yours here

[Sending a string as a file](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-a-string-as-file)

Answer (score 0):

Work in Cakephp 3.7

```
$body = $this->response->getBody();
$body->write('"your", "text"');

$body = $this->response->withBody($body)->withCharset('windows-1251')->withType('text/csv');

return $this->response->withDownload('yourFileName.csv');
```